# Join two files, matching on a column, with repetitions

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, join

How can I get two files A and B, and out put a result like this:

File A:

```
001 Apple, CA
020 Banana, CN
023 Apple, LA
045 Orange, TT
101 Orange, OS
200 Kiwi, AA
```

File B:

```
01-Dec-2013 01.664  001     AAA CAC 1083
01-Dec-2013 01.664  020     AAA CAC 0513
01-Dec-2013 01.668  023     AAA CAC 1091
01-Dec-2013 01.668  101     AAA CAC 0183
01-Dec-2013 01.674  200     AAA CAC 0918
01-Dec-2013 01.674  045     AAA CAC 0918
01-Dec-2013 01.664  001     AAA CAC 2573
01-Dec-2013 01.668  101     AAA CAC 1091
01-Dec-2013 01.668  020     AAA CAC 6571
01-Dec-2013 01.668  023     AAA CAC 2148
01-Dec-2013 01.674  200     AAA CAC 0918
01-Dec-2013 01.668  045     AAA CAC 5135
```

Result:

```
01-Dec-2013 01.664  001     AAA CAC 1083    Apple, CA
01-Dec-2013 01.664  020     AAA CAC 0513    Banana, CN
01-Dec-2013 01.668  023     AAA CAC 1091    Apple, LA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  101     AAA CAC 0183    Orange, OS
01-Dec-2013 01.674  200     AAA CAC 0918    Kiwi, AA
01-Dec-2013 01.674  045     AAA CAC 0918    Orange, TT
01-Dec-2013 01.664  001     AAA CAC 2573    Apple, CA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  101     AAA CAC 1091    Orange, OS
01-Dec-2013 01.668  020     AAA CAC 6571    Banana, CN
01-Dec-2013 01.668  023     AAA CAC 2148    Apple, LA
01-Dec-2013 01.674  200     AAA CAC 0918    Kiwi, AA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  045     AAA CAC 5135    Orange, TT
```

(file A: the number should match to middle number from file B)

Is there any possible way to doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution with awk:

```
awk -v FILE_A="file-A" -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN { while ( ( getline < FILE_A ) > 0 ) { VAL = $0 ; sub( /^[^ ]+ /, "", VAL ) ; DICT[ $1 ] = VAL } } { print $0, DICT[ $3 ] }' file-B
```

Here is a commented version:

```
awk -v FILE_A="file-A" -v OFS="\t" '
BEGIN {

  # Loop on the content of file-A
  # to put the values in a table

  while ( ( getline < FILE_A ) > 0 ){

     # Remove the index from the value
     VAL = $0
     sub( /^[^ ]+ /, "", VAL )

     # Fill the table
     DICT[ $1 ] = VAL
  }
}
{

  # Print the line followed by the
  # corresponding value
  print $0, DICT[ $3 ]

}' file-B
```

Comment: @ Jean, Thanks you for your answer. :)  I got a best result from your help.

Comment: @JOSS, If you're accepting an `awk` answer, you should remove the bash-script tag.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Bash script that does what you're looking for. The script's called `mergeAB.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray A < fileA.txt 

i=0
while read -r B; do
  idx=$(( $i % ${#A[@]} ))

  printf "%s %s" "$B" "${A[$idx]}"
  #echo "i: $i | A#: ${#A[@]} | IDX: $idx"

  let i=i+1
done < fileB.txt
```

When you run it:

```
$ ./mergeAB.bash 
01-Dec-2013 01.664  001     AAA CAC 1083 001 Apple, CA
01-Dec-2013 01.664  020     AAA CAC 0513 020 Banana, CN
01-Dec-2013 01.668  023     AAA CAC 1091 023 Apple, LA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  101     AAA CAC 0183 045 Orange, TT
01-Dec-2013 01.674  200     AAA CAC 0918 101 Orange, OS
01-Dec-2013 01.674  045     AAA CAC 0918 200 Kiwi, AA
01-Dec-2013 01.664  001     AAA CAC 2573 001 Apple, CA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  101     AAA CAC 1091 020 Banana, CN
01-Dec-2013 01.668  020     AAA CAC 6571 023 Apple, LA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  023     AAA CAC 2148 045 Orange, TT
01-Dec-2013 01.674  200     AAA CAC 0918 101 Orange, OS
01-Dec-2013 01.668  045     AAA CAC 5135 200 Kiwi, AA
```

#### Details

The very first thing we do is use the command `readarray` to read the contents of `fileA.txt` into an array. This is a newer feature of Bash 4.x, so if you're using an older version of Bash you can use something like this instead:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a A < fileA.txt
```

The rest of this script's a bit complex but I've left a verbose `echo` in the middle that you can un-comment to see what's going on.

```
$ ./mergeAB.bash | grep i:
i: 0 | A#: 6 | IDX: 0
i: 1 | A#: 6 | IDX: 1
i: 2 | A#: 6 | IDX: 2
i: 3 | A#: 6 | IDX: 3
i: 4 | A#: 6 | IDX: 4
i: 5 | A#: 6 | IDX: 5
i: 6 | A#: 6 | IDX: 0
i: 7 | A#: 6 | IDX: 1
i: 8 | A#: 6 | IDX: 2
i: 9 | A#: 6 | IDX: 3
i: 10 | A#: 6 | IDX: 4
i: 11 | A#: 6 | IDX: 5
```

What's going on here? There's an counter, `$i` that we use to count each line from `fileB.txt` as we loop through it. We then calculate `$idx` by calculating modulo division of the current value of `$i` and the number of lines in `fileA.txt`.

**NOTE:** the length of the array `A`. By calculating `$idx` this way we're able to make it "loop" around from 0 to 5, then 0 to 5 etc. In the debug output above you can see this with the `IDX:` column.

The rest of the script is pretty standard, using `printf` to print the concatenated lines from `fileB.txt` with the corresponding line from `fileA.txt`.

Comment: Thank you!! SIM, that is what i need also learn more about it

Comment: @JOSS - You're quite welcome, thanks for the interesting Q!

Comment: @SIM, I just find out the result doesn't match.....

Comment: file A: the number should match to middle number from file B. do you know how to fix it??

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat b | while read b; do key=$(echo $b | awk '{print $3}'); /bin/echo -n "$b  "; grep -w $key a | cut -d\  -f2-; done
01-Dec-2013 01.664  001     AAA CAC 1083  Apple, CA
01-Dec-2013 01.664  020     AAA CAC 0513  Banana, CN
01-Dec-2013 01.668  023     AAA CAC 1091  Apple, LA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  101     AAA CAC 0183  Orange, OS
01-Dec-2013 01.674  200     AAA CAC 0918  Kiwi, AA
01-Dec-2013 01.674  045     AAA CAC 0918  Orange, TT
01-Dec-2013 01.664  001     AAA CAC 2573  Apple, CA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  101     AAA CAC 1091  Orange, OS
01-Dec-2013 01.668  020     AAA CAC 6571  Banana, CN
01-Dec-2013 01.668  023     AAA CAC 2148  Apple, LA
01-Dec-2013 01.674  200     AAA CAC 0918  Kiwi, AA
01-Dec-2013 01.668  045     AAA CAC 5135  Orange, TT
```

I suspect the `awk` construct can be done in a more elegant way, but it seems to work.

Comment: thanks, this works. but is it possible to use array?

Answer (score 2):

The `join` utility performs an "equality join" on the specified files and writes the result to the standard output.  The "join field" is the field in each file by which the files are compared.

In other words, you have two files that share a column. You can join the lines of those files where the column is equal.

So let's try:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 3 a b
001 Apple, CA 01-Dec-2013 01.664 AAA CAC 1083
020 Banana, CN 01-Dec-2013 01.664 AAA CAC 0513
023 Apple, LA 01-Dec-2013 01.668 AAA CAC 1091
101 Orange, OS 01-Dec-2013 01.668 AAA CAC 0183
200 Kiwi, AA 01-Dec-2013 01.674 AAA CAC 0918
```

Yep, works. But not in the format you specified. So let's swap the files:

```
$ join -1 3 -2 1 b a
001 01-Dec-2013 01.664 AAA CAC 1083 Apple, CA
020 01-Dec-2013 01.664 AAA CAC 0513 Banana, CN
023 01-Dec-2013 01.668 AAA CAC 1091 Apple, LA
101 01-Dec-2013 01.668 AAA CAC 0183 Orange, OS
200 01-Dec-2013 01.674 AAA CAC 0918 Kiwi, AA
```

Much better. Still not quite right, since the joined field shows up first. Awk can fix that up:

```
$ join -1 3 -2 1 b a | awk '{print $2,$3,$1,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}'
01-Dec-2013 01.664 001 AAA CAC 1083 Apple, CA
01-Dec-2013 01.664 020 AAA CAC 0513 Banana, CN
01-Dec-2013 01.668 023 AAA CAC 1091 Apple, LA
01-Dec-2013 01.668 101 AAA CAC 0183 Orange, OS
01-Dec-2013 01.674 200 AAA CAC 0918 Kiwi, AA
```

So there you go. The fields are in the same order. In `awk` you can use `printf` or insert some tabs if you want to get the spacing exact, but I think you'll get the idea.

Comment: Note that you need to sort the input files on the join field for `join` to work properly.

Comment: `join` isn't quite right for the question, either.  There are more lines of B than A; join won't output all the lines. And it destroys the fixed field widths (i.e. eats spaces)

Comment: @RickyBeam - Wrong. `join` is _definitely_ the right tool for this job: `join -1 1 -2 3 -o 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 1.2 1.3 fileA <(sort -k3 fileB)` . You could even preserve the order of lines in `fileB` and the spacing if you so wished, search my posts under the `join` tag if you're curious to see how.

Comment: *Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields.* That rather solidly kills the ordering. `join` is a poor tool for the task; you have not proven otherwise.

Comment: @RickyBeam - in the OP example `file1` is already sorted though in general both have to be sorted so I completely agree here. The fact that `sort` "solidly kills the ordering" is irrelevant because you can re-sort the output back to the initial order. That is, if you're smart enough. I don't feel the need to prove you anything but here are a few examples for you to read [1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216002),[2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206099),[3](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232201).

Comment: sort then unsort *just* to use `join` is lame. This isn't a question about bending `join` to a task; it's about getting a task done, and `join` is clearly a poor tool for the task. (1) all inputs must be sorted, adding additional work to reorder the output. (2) it collapses whitespace, adding additional work to put it back. (3) all together, it's a very cumbersome commandline closely tied to the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

With an array, as requested (entirely in `bash`)...

```
while read num loc; do A[0x$num]=$loc; done < A
while read B; do set -- $B; echo "${B} ${A[0x$3]}"; done < B
```

(works in bash v2)

The first line loads the array "A" from file A.  The *0x$num* bit is to keep everything in the same number base otherwise the leading zeros makes them octal.  The second line reads each line of file B (preserving spaces), sets the positional args from that line, and finally prints the line plus the indexed entry from "A".