# Merge 2 files based on all values of the first column of the first file

Tags: files, awk, merge, join

I need to merge below 2 files:

- **file1**:

> TABLES    REF-IO  HEAD-IO DIFF-IO
>   test    200 500 -300
>   exam    2   3   -1
>   final   2   1   1
>   mail    4   2   2
>   TOTAL   208 506 -298

- **file2**:

> TABLES    REF-SELECT  HEAD-SELECT DIFF-SELECT
>   test    5   7   -2
>   game    3   3   0
>   exam    0   7   -7
>   final   12  6   6
>   TOTAL   20  23  -3

**merged file should be as shown below:**

> TABLES    REF-IO  HEAD-IO DIFF-IO REF-SELECT  HEAD-SELECT DIFF-SELECT
>   test    200 500 -300    5   7   -2
>   exam    2   3   -1  0   7   -7
>   final   2   1   1   12  6   6
>   mail    4   2   2   0   0   0
>   TOTAL   208 506 -298    20  23  -3

Comment: You might want to see `man join`.

Comment: "game" does not appear in the merged file?

Comment: for my case JOIN does not work properly, since I do have the same value in column one of each file.

Comment: `join` can still work if the line order is not important, see  my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {vals[$1] = $2 " " $3 " " $4; next} 
    !($1 in vals) {vals[$1] = "0 0 0"} 
    {$(NF+1) = vals[$1]; print}
' file2 file1
```

```
TABLES REF-IO HEAD-IO DIFF-IO REF-SELECT HEAD-SELECT DIFF-SELECT
test 200 500 -300 5 7 -2
exam 2 3 -1 0 7 -7
final 2 1 1 12 6 6
mail 4 2 2 0 0 0
TOTAL 208 506 -298 20 23 -3
```

Comment: You answer is better than mine because it gives the exact expected result :p But I'm still wondering whether it is normal not to have "game" in the expected result, whereas there is "mail"...

Comment: The OP will have to tell us.

Comment: game should not appear since my aim is to merge the 2 files based on only all values of column one of FILE1. (in case a value does not exist in file2 then it should be filled zeros)

Comment: I have a question why you are giving as input file2 before file1 ?

Comment: The `NR==FNR` condition means the file record number == the cumulative record number, and this is only true for the first file. So I'm reading the values from file2, but not printing any of them. You only care about the keys from file1\

Comment: Can you explain to us mortals what that do and why? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with `join` and preserve line order, headers, footers etc...

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -a 1 -e 0 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2,2.3,2.4 \
<(sort -k2,2 <(nl -ba -nrz file1)) <(sort -k1,1 file2) | \
sort -k1,1n | cut -d\  -f2-
```

result:

```
TABLES REF-IO HEAD-IO DIFF-IO REF-SELECT HEAD-SELECT DIFF-SELECT
test 200 500 -300 5 7 -2
exam 2 3 -1 0 7 -7
final 2 1 1 12 6 6
mail 4 2 2 0 0 0
TOTAL 208 506 -298 20 23 -3
```

How it works:

`nl -ba -nrz file1` numbers the lines in `file1`, the output is then `sort`ed on 2nd field; `file2` is also `sort`ed on 1st field and the results are then `join`ed on 2nd field from 1st input and 1st field from 2nd input, replacing missing input fields with `0`:

```
000003 exam 2 3 -1 0 7 -7
000004 final 2 1 1 12 6 6
000005 mail 4 2 2 0 0 0
000001 TABLES REF-IO HEAD-IO DIFF-IO REF-SELECT HEAD-SELECT DIFF-SELECT
000002 test 200 500 -300 5 7 -2
000006 TOTAL 208 506 -298 20 23 -3
```

this is then sorted on 1st field with `sort -k1,1n` to restore line order and then `cut -d\  -f2-` removes the line numbers. You could further prettify it with `column` e.g. `.... | column -t`:

```
TABLES  REF-IO  HEAD-IO  DIFF-IO  REF-SELECT  HEAD-SELECT  DIFF-SELECT
test    200     500      -300     5           7            -2
exam    2       3        -1       0           7            -7
final   2       1        1        12          6            6
mail    4       2        2        0           0            0
TOTAL   208     506      -298     20          23           -3
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should work:

```
touch resultFile
while read f; do
    header1=$(echo $f | awk '{print $1;}');
    values1=$(echo $f | awk -F "$header1 " '{print $NF;}');
    while read g; do
        header2=$(echo $g | awk '{print $1;}');
        values2=$(echo $g | awk -F "$header2 " '{print $NF;}');
        if [ $header1 = $header2 ]; then
            echo "$header1 $values1 $values2" >> resultFile
        fi
    done < file2
done < file1
```

Headers must be unique, otherwise only the last line found will be merged.

PS: I have considered that "mail" header should not be present in the result as it is not present in both files, as "game" (in your example "mail" is present but not "game").

Comment: mail is intended not to be present in the second file. My aim is to join the 2 files based on only all values of column one of first file. (in case a value does not exist in file2 then it should be filled zeros)

Answer (score 0):

In case you were wondering, it *is* possible to do this with `join`, although the order of the lines is not preserved:

```
(
  join <(head -n1 file1) <(head -n1 file2)
  join -a 1 -e 0 -o '0 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.2 2.3 2.4' \
                    <(sed -n 2,5p file1 | sort) \
                    <(sed -n 2,5p file2 | sort)
  join <(tail -n1 file1) <(tail -n1 file2)
)
```

Output:

```
TABLES REF-IO HEAD-IO DIFF-IO REF-SELECT HEAD-SELECT DIFF-SELECT
exam 2 3 -1 0 7 -7
final 2 1 1 12 6 6
mail 4 2 2 0 0 0
test 200 500 -300 5 7 -2
TOTAL 208 506 -298 20 23 -3
```

Comment: It's worth noting that join requires its input files to be sorted--that often makes it tricky for files with headers. As these files have both headers and footers, it could be downright annoying.

Comment: @laindir - [not really](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216002).