# Join two files based on a column

Tags: awk, join, merge

file1:

```
a, 1    
b, 5    
c, 2    
f, 7
```

file2:

```
a, 2    
f, 9    
g, 3
```

I want to join file 1 and file 2 based on column 1 and get file 3 as below.

file3:

```
a, 1, 2    
b, 5, -    
c, 2, -    
f, 7, 9    
g, -, 3
```

merge the matching values and also keep the specific ones from each file

Comment: what have you tried to solve this? see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43417/join-two-files-with-matching-columns and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122919/merge-2-files-based-on-all-values-of-the-first-column-of-the-first-file for reference...

Answer (score 7):

Using `join`:

```
$ join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o0,1.2,2.2 -e ' -' file1 file2
a, 1, 2
b, 5, -
c, 2, -
f, 7, 9
g, -, 3
```

The standard `join` utility will perform a relational JOIN operation on the two *sorted* input files.

The flags used here tells the utility to expect comma-delimited input (`-t,`) and to produce output for all entries in both files (`-a 1 -a 2`, otherwise it would only produce output for lines with matching first field). We then ask for the join field along with the second column of both files to be outputted (`-o0,1.2,2.2`) and say that any missing field should be replaced by the string `␣-` (space-dash, with `-e ' -'`).

If the input is not sorted, it has to be pre-sorted.  In shells that understands process substitution with `<( ... )`, this my be done through

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o0,1.2,2.2 -e ' -' <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
```

Comment: I didn't even know there is a `join` command, but it's part of the [GNU coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GNU_Core_Utilities_commands) – thanks a lot!

Comment: @dessert It's a standard command that should be available on all Unices.