# Compare first column in different files

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, join

I want to compare one file with other files in the same directory.

`file1.txt` contains:

```
move 34#123#    
get 11#278    
put 33#29#567#23
```

`file1.txt` should compare with files `1.txt` and `2.txt`.

`1.txt` contains:

```
move 11    
put 34    
run 13
```

`2.txt` contains:

```
get 14    
move 66
```

I need the results to be like this:

```
move 2    
get 1    
put 1
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You want the count of the number of `move` and `get` and `put` lines?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){++a[$1]}
    END{for(i in a){print i" "a[i]}}' file1.txt 1.txt 2.txt
put 1
get 1
move 2
```

**Explanation**

- `FNR==NR{a[$1];next}`: when processing `file1.txt`, we mark the occurence of `$1` in associative array `a`.
- `($1 in a){++a[$1]}`: when processing `1.txt` and `2.txt`, we check if `$1` is existed in associative array `a`, if yes, increasing the count by 1.
- Finally, loop through associative array `a`, print the key (first field in files) and its value (number of ocurrences in `1.txt` and `2.txt`).

Here is another solution in `perl`, with the same logic:

```
$ perl -alne '++$i;                  
    if ($. == $i) {
        $h{$F[0]}=0;
        close ARGV if eof;
        next;
    }
    ++$h{$F[0]} if defined $h{$F[0]};
END {
    for (keys %h) {
        print $_." ".$h{$_};
    }
}' file1.txt 1.txt 2.txt
move 2
get 1
put 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Showing an alternative that uses a variety of tools, `grep`, `awk`, `sort`, & `uniq`. Granted it makes use of more tools but I find it easier to understand what's going on vs. AWK.

```
$ for i in 1.txt 2.txt; do grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' $i) file1.txt; done | \
    awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

#### Example

```
$ for i in 1.txt 2.txt; do grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' $i) file1.txt; done | \
    awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
      1 get
      2 move
      1 put
```

#### How it works

Here's the example unrolled a bit.

```
$ for i in 1.txt 2.txt; do 
    grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' $i) file1.txt
  done | \
    awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

The `for` loop goes through the 2 files that we're matching against, `1.txt` and `2.txt`. Each time through the loop we're using the first column from one of these files as a static set of strings to `grep` looking for these in our target file, `file1.txt`. This is the line that does that:

```
$ grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' $i) file1.txt
```

After running that using each file from the `for` loop we take all that output and select only the first column of it:

```
move
put
move
get
```

We then use `sort` and `uniq` to tally up how many of each type we saw.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way with `join`:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -o 0 2.1 <(sort -k1,1 file1.txt) <(cut -d ' ' -f1 1.txt 2.txt | sort | uniq -c)
```

note that the output will be sorted:

```
get 1
move 2
put 1
```

If you want to preserve the order from `file1.txt` e.g.

```
move 2
get 1
put 1
```

you could run:

```
join -j2 -o 1.1 0 2.1 <(nl -ba -nrz file1.txt | sort -k2,2) \
<(cut -d ' ' -f1 1.txt 2.txt | sort | uniq -c) | sort -k1 | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```