# source multiple files and output one file

Tags: bash, source, join

I have a file name "conf1" containing variables like:

```
name='john'
last=''
custom='1000'
```

and another file name conf2 like this:

```
name='john'
last='star'
```

I want to merge between them to one file but in a way that the merged file contain the variable in the same order I source them.

for example if I source conf1 and then conf2 the variable from conf 2 will override conf1. but I will also have the variable that I don't have in conf2.

I want to merge and create 1 file from both of them with only the variables that are unique and was sources last.

required output:conf3

```
name='john'
last='star'
custom='1000'
```

is this possible?

Comment: Consider using a proper configuration library like YAML. I think this would do what you need out of the box. Of course, I don't know what context you are doing this in.

Comment: Is the order of the output that matters or the order of the assignment? (is it OK for custom to show before name in the output as long as `last` is `star` and not `''`)?

Comment: Isn't this what `diff` is designed for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$ awk -F= '{l[$1]=$0};END{for (i in l) print l[i]}' conf1 conf2
custom='1000'
last='star'
name='john'
```

Note that the order of the lines in the output is not guaranteed (based on how `awk` stores the array internally in a hash table), but settings in `conf2` will override those in `conf1`.

where

- `awk -F= ... conf1 conf2` call awk with `=` as separator on conf files.
- `{l[$1]=$0}` store definition of each var, newest overriding oldest
- `END{ ... }` in the end, (after all files processed)
- `for (i in l)` loop for all var,
- `print l[i]` and print it.

Comment: Could you explain the command?  [ExplainShell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=awk+-F%3D+%27{l[%241]%3D%240}%3BEND{for+%28i+in+l%29+print+l[i]}%27+conf1+conf2) is failing me here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join` to merge the two files and *preserve* the order of the keys. Here's an example:
`conf1`:

```
name='john'
last=''
custom='1000'
rule='default'
```

`conf2`:

```
name='joe'
second='none'
fourth='dash'
last='star'
rule='whatever'
```

if you run:

```
{ { join -t= -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 <(sort -t= -k2,2 <(nl -ba -nrz -s= conf1)) \
<(sort -t= -k1,1 conf2); join -t= -1 2 -2 1 -v1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 \
<(sort -t= -k2,2 <(nl -ba -nrz -s= conf1)) <(sort -t= -k1,1 conf2); \
} | sort -k1,1n | cut -d= -f2-; join -t= -1 1  -2 2 -v2 -o 2.1 2.2 2.3 \
<(sort -t= -k1,1 conf1) <(sort -t= -k2,2 <(nl -ba -nrz -s= conf2)) \
| sort -k1,1n | cut -d= -f2-; } > merged_conf
```

the content of `merged_conf` is:

```
name='joe'
last='star'
custom='1000'
rule='whatever'
second='none'
fourth='dash'
```

Maybe it's easier to understand if working with two temporary files. First `n`umber the `l`ines in `conf1` and `conf2` and `sort` them by `2`nd field:

```
sort -t= -k2,2 <(nl -ba -nrz -s= conf1) >conf1.sorted
sort -t= -k2,2 <(nl -ba -nrz -s= conf2) >conf2.sorted
```

the above creates `conf1.sorted`:

```
000003=custom='1000'
000002=last=''
000001=name='john'
000004=rule='default'
```

and `conf2.sorted`:

```
000003=fourth='dash'
000004=last='star'
000001=name='joe'
000005=rule='whatever'
000002=second='none'
```

Now, the same command using the original files *and* the numbered/sorted files:

```
{ { join -t= -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 conf1.sorted <(sort -t= -k1,1 conf2); \
join -t= -1 2 -2 1 -v1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 conf1.sorted \
<(sort -t= -k1,1 conf2); } | sort -k1,1n | cut -d= -f2-; \
join -t= -1 1  -2 2 -v2 -o 2.1 2.2 2.3 <(sort -t= -k1,1 conf1) conf2.sorted \
| sort -k1,1n | cut -d= -f2-; } > merged_conf
```

Explanation:

```
join -t= -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 conf1.sorted <(sort -t= -k1,1 conf2)
```

joins the files based on field `2` from `conf1.sorted` and field `1` from `conf2` printing the common lines but with the values (`2.2`) from `conf2`:

```
000002=last='star'
000001=name='joe'
000004=rule='whatever
```

and

```
join -t= -1 2 -2 1 -v1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 conf1.sorted <(sort -t= -k1,1 conf2)
```

prints the unpairable lines from `conf1.sorted`:

```
000003=custom='1000'
```

they're grouped `{..}` and the output is piped to `sort -k1,1n | cut -d= -f2-` so as to restore the order of keys from the original `conf1`:

```
name='joe'
last='star'
custom='1000'
rule='whatever'
```

then

```
join -t= -1 1  -2 2 -v2 -o 2.1 2.2 2.3 <(sort -t= -k1,1 conf1) conf2.sorted
```

joins based on field `1` from `conf1` and field `2` from `conf2.sorted` printing unpairable lines from the latter:

```
000003=fourth='dash'
000002=second='none'
```

in the same manner, the output is piped to `sort -k1,1n | cut -d= -f2-` so as to restore the order of keys from the original `conf2`:

```
second='none'
fourth='dash'
```

Grouping all the above produces the desired output:

```
name='joe'
last='star'
custom='1000'
rule='whatever'
second='none'
fourth='dash'
```

this is then redirected (`>`) to `merged_conf`. Finally, remove the sorted files:

```
rm conf{1,2}.sorted
```

This could then be repeated for additional config files using `merged_conf` and e.g `conf3` as arguments and so on...

Answer (score 0):

A Perl approach:

```
$ perl -F= -lane '$k{$F[0]}=$F[1]; END{print "$_=$k{$_}" for keys(%k)}' conf1 conf2 
last='star'
name='john'
custom='1000'
```

This is the same idea as Stéphane's answer. It builds a hash where the variable name is the key and its value is the value. Then, once all files have been processed, it prints out the key/value pairs. Note that the order of the lines is not guaranteed, and can change between invocations, but the values of `conf2` will always override those of `conf1`.

Answer (score 0):

For `conf2` to take priority, it must precede `conf1` in the `sort` args.

```
sort -suk1,1 -t= conf2 conf1 | tac
```

Output:

```
name='john'
last='star'
custom='1000'
```

The above does rely on the fact that the labels`custom`, `last` and `name` sort appropriately for your required output order.  However, when the labels are otherwise named, then this mod will work:

```
eval srx=\" 's/^'{name/1,last/2,custom/3}'=&/;' \"   # sort seq: 1,2,3,etc
sort -suk1,1 -t= conf2 conf1 | sed "$srx" | sort -n | cut -d= -f2-
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
name=${name:-John}
last=${last:-}
custom=${custom:-1000}
```

... and similarly in the other file.  Read your shell's manual page. This will set the variables to the specified values unless they are already set and non-null. It will not matter what order you source the files, at least not with the example data that you showed.